# I am getting a File not found exception and I don't know why the path is correct

Tags: java, android, filenotfoundexception

I am writing an app that on hitting the share options on the tool bar with ShareActionProvider it will allow the user to send it songs through email . but I keep getting an exception of FileNotFoundException here is the code and the exception is this

java.io.FileNotFoundException: song.mp3: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

```
        @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    menu.clear();
    MenuInflater inflator = getMenuInflater();
    inflator.inflate(R.menu.sidebar_menu, menu);
    SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu("Themes");
    subMenu.add(0 , blue , 0 , "Blue");
    subMenu.add(0, pink , 1, "Pink");
    items = subMenu.getItem().getItemId();

    // tool bar menu
    ArrayList<Uri> al = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    ArrayList<Uri> emailAl = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.downloads);
    MenuItem mi = menu.findItem(R.id.searchable);
    MenuItem share = menu.findItem(R.id.share);
    mi.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_search_category_default);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.searchable).getActionView();
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    ShareActionProvider sap =(ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(share);
    Intent intentShare = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    Intent intentEmail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    intentShare.setType("audio/mp3");
    intentEmail.setType("audio/mp3");
    Uri uri = null;
    Uri uriEmail = null;
        try{

            for(String file : mp3Files ){
                File filein = new File(file);
                uri = Uri.fromFile(filein);
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filein.getName());
                File outFile = new File(filein.getPath(), filein.getName()); // IMPORTANT! You need to create your file object separately, so you can then pass it to intent as well.. 
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024]; 
                int len; while ( (len = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1){
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                    } 

                    in.close(); 
                    out.close();

                    uriEmail = Uri.fromFile(outFile); // Here you passed the parent directory file.. Pass newly created file object .. 
                    al.add(uri); 
                    emailAl.add(uriEmail);
            }

            } catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String text = "";
    intentShare.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,al );
    intentEmail.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,emailAl);
    intentEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT , "Subject");
    intentEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT , text);

    sap.setShareIntent(intentShare);
    sap.setShareIntent(intentEmail);
    MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener el = new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener(){
        @Override
   public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
        // Do something when action item collapses
        return true; // Return true to collapse action view
    }
```

Here is the mp3files part where mp3files is declared globally

```
    private void ShowLists(){
    files = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory( Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString());

    downloads = files.listFiles(new FileFilter(){
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file){
            String ext = file.getName();
            if(ext.endsWith(".mp3")){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    mp3Files = new String[downloads.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < mp3Files.length; i++){
        mp3Files[i] = downloads[i].getName();
    }
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.downloads, R.id.textviewone , mp3Files);
    ListView downloadsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.downloads);
    downloadsList.setAdapter(adapter);
    if(adapter.isEmpty()){
        downloadsList.setAdapter(null);
    } else {
        downloadsList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

I have also tried using several different ways of getting the downloads directory including the Environment way but it still don't work please help

**EDITED UPDATED**

So I changed my code to this and still not working

```
    try{
            for(File file : mp3Files){
                File filein = new File(file.toString());
                uri = Uri.fromFile(filein);
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filein);
                File outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), filein.getName()); // IMPORTANT! You need to create your file object separately, so you can then pass it to intent as well.. 
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024]; 
                int len; while ( (len = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1){
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                    } 

                    in.close(); 
                    out.close();

                    uriEmail = Uri.fromFile(outFile); // Here you passed the parent directory file.. Pass newly created file object .. 
                    al.add(uri); 
                    emailAl.add(uriEmail);
            }
            } catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: the most important part in method where you insert data into `mp3Files` attributes, please post the code.

Comment: Looks like `mp3Files` is just the file names, not the full path to the file on disk.

Comment: Log the file path after `File filein = new File(file);` using `filein.getAbsolutePath()`. Then you know where is it pointing.

Comment: Okay I posted the code for mp3files

Comment: @Joshua I'm not sure where file in.getAbsolutePath goes by what means should I put It ????

Comment: I tries filein.getAbsolutePath() it did not work it still gives me the exception

Comment: Use `Log.e("Path", filein.getAbsolutePath());`. See what is the path output to logcat.

Comment: There is nothing in my log cat that showed up @Joshua

Comment: `File filein = new File(file.toString());` what is this supposed to do? why not use `file` directly?

Comment: Because it says their is no applicable contstructor for that only thing I can think of was that

Comment: How can I use file directly ? @njzk2

Comment: what i am trying to say is `file` is a file already, and `filein` is a file too, and presumably you can simply use `file` in place of `filein`

Answer (score 1):

`mp3Files` is just the file names, not the full path to the file on disk.

```
mp3Files[i] = downloads[i].getName();
```

You are getting FileNotFound because you can't `new File()` with just the name and expect it to know where to look for that file.

Needs to be this, but as you can see, `mp3Files` is not necessary to use.

```
mp3Files[i] = downloads[i];
```

In other words, `mp3Files = files.listFiles(...)`

Then, this loop could just be `for (File file : mp3Files)`

```
for(String file : mp3Files ){
    File filein = new File(file);
    uri = Uri.fromFile(filein);
```

If you really want the adapter to show only the names of the files, then you can implement your own ArrayAdapter class to accept a `File[]`, then display only the `getName()` of that `File` in the `getView()` method.

Also, checking `adapter.isEmpty()` and setting a null adapter is not really necessary. If the adapter is empty, no data is shown. If you want to display an empty view, then ListView class has a `setEmptyView` method.

Comment: What for loop? The `adapter` should accept `downloads`, or make `mp3Files = files.listFiles `

Comment: So it should be (File file : files.list files){ ... } or

Comment: Which loop are you refering to? The one before the adapter can be removed. The one in `onCreateOptionsMenu` can be left alone, I think. Assuming the previous comments are followed. Specifically, `mp3Files = files.listFiles`

Comment: Well I did what you told me to do but now I'm getting this error java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyChildActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to null array

Comment: Well, sorry. I cannot be sure what is null, though. `downloads` seems like it can be removed, so that's my guess. If you have another question, though, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button, and provide the full stacktrace

Comment: I already removed the parent activity and it is still giving me that error

Comment: Okay @cricket_007 I am still getting the same exception and I have updated code on top in the post . so basically same problem

Comment: `File filein = new File(file.toString());` <-- Why? You already have a `File` named `file`. What is the purpose of `filein`?

Comment: Well the file is of type File it looks like this for(File file : mp3files) so it won't let me make a new File (file); since mp3files has to be of type Files[] to make the mp3files = files.listFiles(); so how do I do that I can't just pass in the file into File filein = new File(file);

Comment: And if I do for(String file : mp3files) it will give me an error and also if I change mp3files to string I am back where I started :(

Comment: Oh wait I see what you are saying hold up lemmie try

Comment: Okay I got this error java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/received_files: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)

Comment: I passed in file where I was passing in filein and got that exception in my log

Comment: Okay, so now you have a directory that at least exists on the filesystem.

Comment: Okay yes so what do I do now ?

Comment: Debug the error just like I have shown? `/storage/emulated/0/Download/` is coming from `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`, so where does `"received_files"` come from? If you want files, then make sure you are iterating over files, not a directory. Add some `Log` statements to print out the filepaths.

Comment: I just got rid of the file in part and put in downloads and it worked ;D